# What is the correct way to modify a bass bridge to accept thicker guage strings?

Tags: strings, bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar, bridge, 5-string-bass-guitar

Recently, I tried to restring one of my 5-strings and found out that the low B string wouldn't fit through the bridge.  The bass is an LTD B55

I was thinking of drilling/boring the hole to be wider, but is this the right thing to do?

I don't want to ruin the bridge in a way that it won't resonate correctly or that it won't be able to accept thinner gauge strings.

Any suggestions as to how I should modify the bridge to accept a thicker gauge string?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I wouldn't recommend this at all!  Get it professionally done, as you have stated you could ruin the bridge that could create noise.  I had a bass that was perfectly normal (2nd hand bass) but had the bridge filed down for lower action.  Unfortunately it created a buzzing that drove me to just getting a new bass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly honest, I wouldn't recommend this at all! Get it professionally done, as you have stated you could ruin the bridge that could create noise. I had a bass that was perfectly normal (2nd hand bass) but had the bridge filed down for lower action. Unfortunately it created a buzzing that drove me to just getting a new bass.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have a 2011 Fender American Deluxe Jazz V. I went to change the stock strings for a set of flat wounds. The B string is a 0.132, which is a big fat string. I can string through the body or through the bridge. Either way the wrapped end with the ball would not fit through either way leaving about an inch to go to get the ball at the bridge.

I did not have to drill anything. I just strung through the bridge and used the tuner to pull it into place. I am by no means an expert on this, but it worked for me.